# How to hide element in page "B.php" by clicking a checkbox in Page "A.php" using javascript or AJAX or any other way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

http://hespv.ca/solar-resources/solar-installer-tools/fr-component-generator

In This tool on step 2 i want to do like, if i check ULTRA-FLASH in Anchor types which is Page "A.php" then Select foot should disappear. Select foot coulmn is coming from Page "B.php"
Code of B.php is mostly same as  A.php
**# Header 1 #

Code of Page "A.php"------**

```
<?php
function radialAnchors($roof_id){

    require_once("conn.php");
    require_once('query.php');

    $anchors = sqlQuery("SELECT anchors.anchor_id, anchors.code, anchors.href, anchors.image_src, anchors.description
            FROM roof_types INNER JOIN anchors
            ON roof_types.roof_id = anchors.roof_type_fk
            WHERE roof_types.roof_id = $roof_id
            ORDER BY anchors.priority ASC", $conn);

    $checked = 0;
    foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
        ?>
        <div class="row anchor-row">
            <div class="col-2-12 center">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <a href="<?php echo $anchor['href']; ?>" target="_blank">
                        <img src="<?php echo $anchor['image_src']; ?>"alt="<?php echo $anchor['code']; ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col- md-1-12 md-show sm-hide">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-8-12 md-10-12 center">
                <h2><?php echo $anchor['code']; ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $anchor['description']; ?></p>
                <p><a href="<?php echo $anchor['href']; ?>" target="_blank">Find out more</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1-12 center">
                <br><br><input type="radio" name="anchorRadios" id="anchor<?php echo $anchor['anchor_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $anchor['anchor_id']; ?>" <?php if(!$checked++) echo 'checked'; ?>>
                <label for="anchor<?php echo $anchor['anchor_id']; ?>"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understandings you need to hide select foot when you select ULTRA-FLASH. This you can do using jquery. write change listener for your ULTRA-FLASH on change you can hide select foot div completely.

```
$(document).on('change', '#ultra-flash-id', function(){
      this.checked ?  $("#select-foot-id").hide() :  $("#select-foot-id").show();

 });
```

Comment: Should i put this jQuery code in seprate file or in one of those PHP pages.

Comment: you can put this code in A.php file or any javascript file if you have. use <script>above code </script> in your php file and change your element id into actual ids

Comment: I just Tried it on Sample code as i dont wanna mess with actual code until this works. But this Jquery code doesnt work.

Comment: My sample code  <html>
<head>


<body>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hi" name="subscribe" value="newsletter">
    <label for="hi">Subscribe to newsletter?</label>
  </div>
<script>

$(document).on('change', '#hi', function(){
      this.checked ?  $("#hello").hide(); :  $("#hello").show();;

 });
</script>
<div id="hello">
<p>Welcome to our website. We provide tutorials on various subjects.</p>
</div>
</head>
</body>
<html>

Comment: use this code. i have created codepen. [link](http://codepen.io/dineshu07/pen/aWRMKL) <html> <head>  </head><body> <div> <input type="checkbox" id="hi" name="subscribe" value="newsletter"> <label for="hi">Subscribe to newsletter?</label> </div> <script> $(document).on('change', '#hi', function(){ this.checked ? $("#hello").hide() : $("#hello").show();}); </script> <div id="hello"> <p>Welcome to our website. We provide tutorials on various subjects.</p> </div> </body> <html>

Comment: Thanks Dinesh that works perfectly but what if our <div id="hello"> is on page "B.php". And our Checkbox Is on page "A.php" Will this code work for that. If not then How can i access that element.?

Comment: welcome. please accept my answer. if the those A.php and B.php outputs are in the same html page then this method works.